# tables are truncated with "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" to validate

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

NB: Spring Boot 2.1.10 + Spring Cloud Greenwich.SR3

I have two Spring Data JPA services accessing the same external database (which is MySQL) and sharing a common domain:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "first_name") @NotNull
    private String firstname;
    private LocalDate birth;
    private Integer votes = 0;
}
```

In the first service (producer) I added a data.sql for samples insertion:

```
insert into person(first_name) values ('foobar');
insert into person(first_name) values ('scoubidou');
```

And the following properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

In the second service (consumer) I just want to use the schema without modifying it at startup, so I used those properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never
```

When starting the producer, the DB schema is created and filled with sample entities.
But when I start the consumer, then the entities table is truncated.
Does anybody know how the table would gat emptied and how to avoid it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This property eventually solved the issue:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
```

Maybe there is a connection mislead with spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `create-drop` on your producer service. Read [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/)

> - none: The default for MySQL. No change is made to the database    structure.
> - update: Hibernate changes the database according to the given entity     structures.
> - create: Creates the database every time but does not drop it on       close.
> - create-drop: Creates the database and drops it when SessionFactory       closes.

try to use `create` only

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Comment: thx but that will only prevent the db schema from being dropped after producer stop; and I don't stop it on that use case